# How do I Convert Array[Row] to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

How do I convert this one row to a dataframe?

```
val oneRowDF = myDF.first // gives Array[Row]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

In my answer, df1 is a DataFrame [text: string, y : int], just for testing - `val df1 = sc.parallelize(List("a", 1")).toDF("text", "y")`.

```
val schema = StructType(
    StructField("text", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("y", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)
val arr = df1.head(3); // Array[Row]
val dfFromArray = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sparkContext.parallelize(arr), schema);
```

You can also map parallelized array and cast every row:

```
val dfFromArray = sparkContext.parallelize(arr).map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getInt(1)))
    .toDF("text", "y");
```

In case of one row, you can run:

```
val dfFromArray = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(row)).map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getInt(1)))
    .toDF("text", "y");
```

In Spark 2.0 use SparkSession instead of SQLContext.

Comment: Why downvote? 100% answer to question, tested and working

Comment: Agreed, I even think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @BelkacemLahouel Thanks :) Please up vote if you found it helpful :)

Comment: @BelkacemLahouel Thanks, I didn't notice the notification. Well, I think each downvote should have reason, but some people don't do it. Nevertheless, some people may use the answer so it's worth keeping it :)

Answer (score 9):

You do not want to do that :

If you want a subpart of the whole dataFrame just use `limit` api.

**Example:**

```
scala> val d=sc.parallelize(Seq((1,3),(2,4))).toDF
d: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int]

scala> d.show
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  2|  4|
+---+---+


scala> d.limit(1)
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [_1: int, _2: int]

scala> d.limit(1).show
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
+---+---+
```

Still if you want to explicitly convert an Array[Row] to DataFrame , you can do something like

```
scala> val value=d.take(1)
value: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,3])

scala> val asTuple=value.map(a=>(a.getInt(0),a.getInt(1)))
asTuple: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,3))

scala> sc.parallelize(asTuple).toDF
res6: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int]
```

And hence now you can show it accordingly !

Comment: Note that `Dataset.limit(n: Int)` function is available since Spark 2.0.0.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `List<Row>`, then it can directly be used to create a `dataframe` or `dataset<Row>` using `spark.createDataFrame(List<Row> rows, StructType schema)`. Where spark is SparkSession in spark 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the scaladocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@baseRelationToDataFrame(baseRelation:org.apache.spark.sql.sources.BaseRelation):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) - I'd recommend `RDD[Row]` here, which means you need to get there. Should be easiest with [makeRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@makeRDD[T](seq:Seq[T],numSlices:Int)(implicitevidence$2:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]). You'll also need a schema corresponding to your `Row`, Which you can [directly pull from it](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row@schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType).

... how did you get `Array[Row]` in the first place?